# select random columns from database

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table question_bank, structure of table is

```
question_id | question | a | b | c| d | correct_ans
```

i can show user random questions. but is there any way to select random columns as well? i want to shuffle the options of question as well.
i am doing

```
 {
    $query = "SELECT * from question_bank where exam_name='$subject' and exam_class_id='$class_id' order by rand() limit 4";


    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $all = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $all[] = $row;
    }

    $_SESSION['result'] = $all;
    ?>
<form action="result.php" name="form1" method="post" id="quiz">
<?php
echo "<input type='text' name='subject_id' value='$class_id'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='subject_name' value='$subject'>";
foreach ($_SESSION['result'] as $read_all_data)
 {
    $id=$read_all_data['id'];
 echo $read_all_data['question']."</br>";

$random_option=array($read_all_data['a'],$read_all_data['b'],$read_all_data['c'],$read_all_data['d']);
$random_keys=array_rand($random_option,4);


echo "A:<input type ='radio' value ='a'  name='$id' >".$random_option[$random_keys[0]]."</br>";
echo "B:<input type ='radio' value ='b'  name='$id' >".$random_option[$random_keys[1]]."</br>";
echo "C:<input type ='radio' value ='c'  name='$id' >".$random_option[$random_keys[2]]."</br>";
echo "D:<input type ='radio' value ='d'  name='$id' >".$random_option[$random_keys[3]]."</br>";

}

?>
<input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit1'> </form>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? What if one of the options is "all of the above" or "a) and c)" ?

Comment: that's why i am doing this using php. because all the options are stored in $_SESSION['result'] and i am shuffling after storing values in $_SESSION. i am also confused . my teacher asked me to do so.

Comment: See normalization. You've made this problem unnecessarily complicated by virtue of poor design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need a rethink before we start. Get a piece of paper and a pen.
Think what is it you want to do, then write it down in pseudo code. 
If I'm reading you right this seems to be some question/answer bank.

So I would do this.

```
    $query = "SELECT * from question_bank where exam_name='$subject' and exam_class_id='$class_id' order by rand() limit 4";


     $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


        $all = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            $questions = array();
            $questions[] = array('a',$row['a']);
            $questions[] = array('b',$row['b']);
            $questions[] = array('c',$row['c']);
            $questions[] = array('d',$row['a']),


            $questions = shuffle($questions);



            echo "A:<input type ='radio' value ='$question[0][0]'  name='$row['question_id]' >".$question[0][1]."</br>";
            echo "B:<input type ='radio' value ='$question[1][0]'  name='$row['question_id]' >".$question[1][1]."</br>";
            echo "C:<input type ='radio' value ='$question[2][0]'  name='$row['question_id]' >".$question[2][1]."</br>";
            echo "D:<input type ='radio' value ='$question[3][0]'  name='$row['question_id]' >".$question[3][1]."</br>";



        }
```

Comment: Not my best code and a bit hard/fast but does this help?

Comment: thanks sir, that helped me to rethink and i got what i wanted using shuffle function. i was not aware of this function.

Comment: Same here but php has a huge bank of array functions and other functions, if you can think it its probably already been done. That's what programming is these days to take the bits that people have done and gel them together to make your own. Course knowing php from the base up comes in handy as well!

Answer (score 1):

The 2 lines of PHP you have used to randomise the answers is a pretty effective solution.

However your code won't work because you have no current way of knowing which random answer is submitted in the form. The values of the `<input>` tags needs to be the answer value. `$random_option[$random_keys[X]]`.

Also consider checking the result of [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) is not an error (!== false) and using mysqli_error to write details of the error to a log somewhere.

If you really want to randomise the data in MySQL and use a solution that scales. Move the answer options to a separate table and use a second query to get those results. This would allow you to get answers in a random order and also handle different numbers of possible answers in future.

```
question_bank:
question_id | question | correct_ans

answer_bank:
answer_id | question_id | answer
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use data from INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS col_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = 'your_table' AND table_schema = 'your_database' 
ORDER BY RAND();
```

This query brings each time all the table columns in a random order so you will be able to store them in an array and proceed as you want.